# Alternative for VC++ 6.0

Tags: windows-vista, visual-c++, visual-basic

Hi all I'm using Vista(32-bit). I need to work on VC++ for MFC applications. I have installed Visual C++ 6.0 on my system which is incompatible. Can someone please suggest an alternative for VC++ 6.0. By googling, I found an application called Source Insight, capable of replicating VC++, so i installed it, but I didn't understand how to get started. Any other suggestions ?Please help me.

**EDIT:** I've installed whole VB 6.0 package which means VC++ is also installed by default. What I'm asking is - since VC++ 6.0 is incompatible in Windows Vista/7, I'm looking for an alternative application which can help me in building MFC applications.

Comment: I don't know your age but if you are a student you can get VS2010 Professional for free from: https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx

Comment: I think the big question is why you tried VC++ 6.0, which is old, buggy, and unsupported on Vista and 7.  (One of my recommendations for upgrading to Vista was to go from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008, due to some incompatibilities.)  Does the project depend on VC++ 6?  Is that what you have?  Do you have an XP system you can use?

Comment: @ Davis Thornley - Thanks for your prompt reply. I have to use Visual C++ 6.0 because it's the only IDE used in my office for building MFC applications. So I got a license key of VC++ from my office to install it on to my laptop so that I can practice at home too. And now I've heard of something called Windows XP emulator. If I install it on to my laptop, will I be able to get VC++ 6.0 running?

Answer (score 4):

I think your only option is to buy Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 and migrate the apps to it. There's few changes between them - they'll upgrade your MFC app and you'll be able to work on it almost as before.

There isn't much else out there that supports MFC.

Alternatives: get QT and migrate your app using the [MFC to QT migration framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-walkthrough.html).

Comment: Edited the question dude. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Well, have you tried to install WinXP on a VirtualBox image and then installing VC++ 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

I'll get the obvious out of the way - [Visual Studio 2010 Express C++](http://www.microsoft.com/express/windows/)

Comment: I thought the express versions didn't support MFC well - no editor for example, no resource compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Microsoft's VB6, then you probably also have VC6, which is on the same installation disk.

Although no longer supported, it's quite capable of handling C++ and MFC.

Comment: harry - you might want to re-read the question which has been edited since you posted.

Comment: @ harrymc - Dude I've installed whole VB 6.0 package which means VC++ is also installed by default. What I'm asking is - since VC++ 6.0 is incompatible in Windows Vista/7, I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: @Rahul: Dude, VC++ 6.0 is a uncomfortable to use for debug in Win7, but is certainly not incompatible. Don't believe everything Microsoft is telling you.

Comment: @ harrymc - Thanks for your reply. I have to use Visual C++ 6.0 because it's the only IDE used in my office for building MFC applications. So I got a license key of VC++ from my office to install it on to my laptop so that I can practice at home too. And now I've heard of something called Windows XP emulator. If I install it on to my laptop, will I be able to get VC++ 6.0 running?

Comment: @Rahul: In theory, if you install VC++ in XP Mode, it should work just fine. But it's something that I never tried.

Comment: @Rahul: If you have problems installing Microsoft's XP Mode, look into http://www.vmlite.com/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using .NET for your needs but if you MUST use mfc then you could try using a Virtual Machine (I use VMWare VM Player but i hear most/all VM programs are good) and install windows XP (I believe windows 98 wont work or has problems). If your a student i hear you can get a free version of Visual Studios 2010 Ultimate (maybe not Ultimate edition but some editions. I believe Ultimate was what the two different people who go to two different schools said)